# Passing a where clause in a predicate expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have the following predicate expression.

```
public IQueryable<T> Find(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return //boolean
    }
```

Here is where I am calling the method:

```
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        author.AuthorName = authorName;

        using (var context = new AspBlogRepository<Author>())
        {
            if (context.Find(e => e.AuthorName == authorName))
            {
                //do nothing
            }
            context.Add(author);   
        }
    }
```

I get an error saying that I you cannot convert an IQueryable to bool.  I just want to be able to use my predicate expression to see if the author is already in the database.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This `if` is pointless, isn't it? `if (context.Find(e => e.AuthorName == authorName))
            {
                //do nothing
            }
            context.Add(author);` Have you forgotten to add an `else` before `context.Add`?

Comment: Not in this case because EF will throw an error if I try to insert an author who is already in the database.

Comment: @LanceCollins in this case `do nothing` is also pointless. Inverse condition and remove that empty block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IQueryable<T> Find(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return //boolean
    }
```

The problem is here, if you indeed return boolean.  If this method is inside your context, you would first need to resolve `Author` and then filter the `Authors` in your repository.

If this is an EF context, and you have access to the EF context in your repository, you should be able to get the db set like this:

```
var entitySet = context.Set<T>();
```

Then, you can run your predicate against the `entitySet` returning the filtered results.

Answer (score 1):

Error says it all. `context.Find(e => e.AuthorName == authorName)` is returning `IQueryable<T>`. `If` is expecting a `bool`

So your usage of `if (context.Find(e => e.AuthorName == authorName))` is wrong. Change it to

```
if (context.Find(e => e.AuthorName == authorName).Any())
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`context.Find` returns an `IQueryable<T>`. Your code could instead look like:

```
if (context.Find(e => e.AuthorName == authorName).Count() == 1)
{
    //do nothing
}
```